# Getting the index of a form element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple input boxes with the attribute `name="user[]"`

When a button is clicked for a particular input I need to find out at what index of `user` was clicked.

I've tried a few method like `.index()`, `.attr('name")`, but I cant find out the index.

How is this possible?

```
<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="user[]"> <!-- index 0 -->
    <button class="btn btn-primary"> 
</div>
<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="user[]"> <!-- index 1 -->
    <button class="btn btn-primary">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="user[]"> <!-- index 2 -->
    <button class="btn btn-primary">
</div>
...
```

new div can be added by clicking a button.
This is used for a user invite form so there are no ids.

I need something like this

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    var index = $(this).parent().children('input').getTheIndex();
    // where the index is defined by the use of [] 
});
```

Comment: Please post your code - Html, css, jquery.

Comment: Well, don't post the css as it's irrelevant. But please post your html and javascript/jquery.

Comment: The only elements that MUST have identical names are radio buttons. check boxes "could" and if so, you will get their values as a comma separated list of values. But, for regular textboxes, the names should be unique.  Also, FYI, id attribute values should ALWAYS be unique.

Comment: Please create an example of what you're trying to accomplish – "[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)." It's difficult to offer actual assistance with what we can't see, with only a few details that are out-of-context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) finds the index of an element within the given collection.

So, to search among the `name="user[]"` inputs, you'll first need to find all of them:

```
var index = $(':text[name="user[]"]')...;
```

Then, you can determine the `.index()` of the current input among them:

```
var index = ...index(currentInput);
```

Example:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
    var allUsers = $('[name="user[]"]');

    var user = $(this).siblings('[name="user[]"]');
    var index = allUsers.index(user.get(0)); // get the native DOM node for the search

    console.log(index); // 0, 1, ...

    console.log(user.get(0) === allUsers.get(index)); // true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="user[]"> <!-- index 0 -->
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Test</button>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="user[]"> <!-- index 1 -->
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Test</button>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="user[]"> <!-- index 2 -->
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Test</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**If the buttons each relate to a specific hidden element, this will do it:**

```
  var $users = $("input[type=hidden]");
  var $buttons = $(".btn-primary");
  $buttons.on("click", function(){

    // Get the index of the button, since it will match the
    // index of the input
    alert("Button index was: " + $buttons.index(this));

    // Get the index of the hidden element that comes just before the 
    // button that was clicked:
    alert("Hidden index was: " + $users.index(this.previousElementSibling));    
  });
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cvnwr89p/5/

By the way, you need to close your `<button>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set `data` attribute of that input boxes to the something like `data-user-id=42` so you can look for `checked` boxes and get their `data` attribute. If you want something like "index within all form elements" than you need something like `document.getElementById("form").elements` where you can look for you inputs...

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
$('.btn-primary').on('click', function() {
    console.log($('.btn-primary').index($(this)))
});
```

Comment: Really? That's the exact answer I posted several minutes before you.

Comment: Eh? Your answer wasn't visible when I posted mine. And my answer is different.

Comment: My answer was posted over 5 minutes before yours and I have since updated my answer to be more comprehensive, but when you posted yours, it was virtually the same as mine. You probably didn't see the grey bar indicating that a new answer had been posted when you added your answer, but SO will alert you this way so you can check new content before you finally click the Post Answer button.